# Admin login is considered on front end

Tags: admin, login

I am facing a weird problem as I am considered as I am placing the order from backend where as I have placed the order from frontend.

```
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');

        if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {

            Mage::log(1);

        }else{

            Mage::log(2)
        }
    }else{

        Mage::log(3);
    }
```

When this file is called from the front end cart page the output in  log is 1 which is supposed to be 3 because the session is suppose to fetch the data if I am placing order from admin side.

Comment: just make your question more elaborate your problem, add more info

Comment: why you are getting admin session in frontend.